# Disabling CheckBox in the KendoGrid Template using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid with column UniqueId that has a ClientTemplate with Checkbox. This is a small part of my code:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId)
                      .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='primaryBox' id='#= UniqueId #' value='#= UniqueId #'>#= UniqueId #</input>");
```

I would like to disable this Checkbox using jquery (something like that:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId)
                      .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='primaryBox' checked='true' style='display:none;' id='#= UniqueId #'>#= UniqueId #</input>");)
```

How can I do this? (I want to keep column UniqueId, only to disable the Checkbox). Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: So your goal is to display the checkbox in the column and make it to where the user can't change the value? Or are you wanting to not display the checkbox at all?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have a  DropDownList and when a user clicks on the an item of the list, I want to show the check box.When the user clicks on the other item, I want to hide it. I have used              $('.primaryBox').hide() and $('.primaryBox').show(),but the grid that includes this UniqueId column always shows the check box on the first click . That is my problem.

Comment: I solved my problem using two grids: one with  a checkbox and another without checkbox. It is not so clever, but it works fine.